# html/php login pages (automatic login to second page based in login of index page)

Tags: php, html, single-sign-on

I have 2 pages. There is authentication form in both pages. I want the second page to be logged in automatically on successful login of first page (index).

How do I do this? Should I use single sign on, if yes how to use single sign on in this case?

Comment: How do u use the authentication? upon successful first login, make the session active for the second page

Comment: Are you using  sessions?

Comment: Simply you're looking for _SESSIONS_

Answer (score 0):

In general there should be a single login form and mechanism in place. Authentication should be checked for other pages if needed.
Here is a basic mechanism

loginform.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usr']))){
    if(!is_null($_SESSION['usr']) || $_SESSION['usr'] != ''){ 
    header('Location: yourpage.php');
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title> Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <form method="post" action="login.php">
      <div class="txt-big">Login</div>
      <div class="field">
       <label for="user_name">Username </label>
       <input type="text" size="30" name="usr" id="usr" class="text-input">
      </div>

      <div class="field">
       <label for="user_name">Password </label>
       <input type="password" size="30" name="pswd" id="pswd" class="text-input">
      </div> 

       <div class="field">

      <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" class="btn btn-submit" >
       <input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="reset" class="btn btn-submit">
      </div>

    </form>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require ("mysqli.inc.php");
$username = $_REQUEST['usr'];
$password = $_REQUEST['pswd'];
$query = "Select * FROM `admin` WHERE username LIKE '" . $username . "' AND password LIKE '" . $password . "' ";
$r = mysqli_do($query);
if( $r ){
$_SESSION['usr'] = $username;
header("Location:"." yourpage.php");
}
else{
header("Location:"." loginform.php");
}
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location: loginform.php');
?>
```

in yourpage.php check if logged in. This is a basic way of doing

yourpage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usr']) || is_null($_SESSION['usr']) || $_SESSION['usr'] == ''){
    header("Location:"." loginform.php");
        } 

....
....
    ?>
```

Note: This is a basic sample and not intended to be a total solution. Need to be enhanced!